# Using "WHERE" twice with (Random) MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, using

Need some help?

This works

```
 $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM 
         (SELECT * FROM $TableDir 
             WHERE dir_ranking = '1' 
             ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 16) 
         x ORDER BY dir_date_listed ASC";
```

It selects random from "$TableDir" where Ranking = 1 and limits to 16 records

But I need to filter out another option. I need to filter `"dir_approved = Y"` as well
I tried this

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM 
         (SELECT * FROM $TableDir 
             WHERE dir_ranking = '1' 
             ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 16) 
      WHERE dir_approved = 'Y' x 
            ORDER BY dir_date_listed ASC";
```

And this

```
        $sql = "
            SELECT * FROM 
                 (SELECT * FROM $TableDir 
                     WHERE dir_ranking = '1' AND WHERE dir_approved = 'Y' 
                       ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 16) 
               x ORDER BY dir_date_listed ASC";
```

None of the Last two above resulted in any data

Is there another sequence or way to get this working

Answer (score 1):

It isn't `WHERE x = y WHERE a = b`, the format is `WHERE x = y AND a = b`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! it works ! dunno why i did it like that! I think because of the (random) i though i had to redo the WHERE!

Comment: No problem! Also my apologies, I also noticed you put your first `WHERE` on the outside of your subquery. If the `WHERE` applies to the subquery then it should be `SELECT ( yourColumns WHERE condition` whereas yours was `SELECT (yourColumns) WHERE condition`